# Better way to recover edited vim files

Tags: shell-script, find, vim, data-recovery

Much too often my Linux box gets plugged off with lots of open `vim` sessions. To continue my work I have to open all files and decide whether to continue with the saved file or with the swap file. I use

```
for file in $(find ~/git -name *.swp); do
  gvim "$(echo $file | sed 's/.swp$//;s_/\._/_')"
done
```

which does what I want (yes, I prefer separate instances of `gvim` over one instance with multiple buffers, and yes, theoretically this could fail for certain path names I don't have in real life), but is a nasty way to script it.

I'd rather do something like

```
find ~/git -name *.swp -exec gvim -r {} \;
```

but this doesn't leave me the decision whether the the saved or the recovery version is the one to continue with.

Can you think of some other more straight-forward way to reach my goal?

Comment: What is `gvim`?

Comment: A "graphical" vim instance, running on your X11 desktop, instead of in a terminal emulator.

Comment: Tangentially related to your question: you might find [this plugin](https://github.com/chrisbra/Recover.vim) useful.

Answer (score 1):

You've got one `gvim` command with no options where you manipulate the filename, and one `gvim -r` where you're passing the swap file.

If you like what the `for` loop does, try this (which is a bash-only version):

```
find ~/git -name *.swp -exec bash -c 'f=${1%.swp}; f=${f/\/./\/}; gvim "%f"' x {} \;
```

Passing the "x" to bash sets $0 to "x", so the find `{}` placeholder becomes $1.

Comment: Well put there glenn